# Static reshape of Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I am experimenting with doing bicubic interpolation of some gridded data using Eigen, and I can't figure out how to reshape the 16x1 column vector of coefficients into a 4x4 matrix.  Ideally I would like to do something along the lines of https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/pull-request/41/reshape/diff without any copying, but I can't make heads or tails of the docs.  Alternatively, a map would be fine as well, but I can't figure out how to use a map on an already existing matrix.

More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation

```
/// The inverse of the A matrix for the bicubic interpolation 
/// (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation)
static const double Ainv_data[16*16] = {
     1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    -3,  3,  0,  0, -2, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     2, -2,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -3,  3,  0,  0, -2, -1,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2, -2,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,
    -3,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -2,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0, -3,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -2,  0, -1,  0,
     9, -9, -9,  9,  6,  3, -6, -3,  6, -6,  3, -3,  4,  2,  2,  1,
    -6,  6,  6, -6, -3, -3,  3,  3, -4,  4, -2,  2, -2, -2, -1, -1,
     2,  0, -2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0, -2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,
    -6,  6,  6, -6, -4, -2,  4,  2, -3,  3, -3,  3, -2, -1, -2, -1,
     4, -4, -4,  4,  2,  2, -2, -2,  2, -2,  2, -2,  1,  1,  1,  1};

Eigen::Matrix<double, 16, 16> Ainv(Ainv_data);

Eigen::Matrix<double, 16, 1> f;
f.setRandom();
Eigen::Matrix<double, 16, 1> alpha = Ainv*f;
// This next line works, but it is making a copy, right?
Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> a(alpha.data());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last line is indeed doing a copy, so you can use a Map as follow:

```
Map<Matrix4d,Eigen::Aligned> a(alpha.data());
```

`a` behaves like a `Matrix4d` and it is read-write. The `Eigen::Aligned` flag tells Eigen that the pointer you pass to Map is properly aligned for vectorization. The only difference with a pure Matrix4d is that the C++ type is not the same.

Comment: With this map call, is it also doing a copy?  Or just essentially generating a view on the internal data of the alpha matrix?

Comment: Indeed, there is no copy here, modifying `a` will modify `alpha` too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, in the end I went to a STL solution for this part since I needed to store a Matrix4d in a structure and I kept getting errors with alignment (I followed the instructions), and in the end i just gave up.  This was very helpful

Comment: if you get errors with alignment try `Map<Matrix4d, Eigen::AutoAlign>(...)`. As far as I understand it, this should not happen in your example because `alpha.data()` should be 16-byte aligned. However if you write something like `Map<Matrix4d, Eigen::AutoAlign>(alpha.data()+1)` you're almost certain to get alignment errors!

Comment: Nope, you should rather ignore this template parameter: `Map<Matrix4d>` or define it to its default value `0`, for instance to specify strides: `Map<Matrix4d,0,Stride<> >`. It turns out that `AutoAlign==0`, but that's just coincidence.